# accessing dynamically loaded elements in phantomjs

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I'm sending a page event:

`page.sendEvent('click', 650, 430);`

This clicks a link that dynamically loads an element over ajax. Is it too late to access this dynamically loaded element via `page.evaluate`? I can't seem to return anything whatsoever in anything dynamically created on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far the simplest dynamic way is to catch console messages, like described here http://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/wiki/Interface#Callbacks

```
page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg) {
    console.log(msg);
};
```

In case you want to send some binary data, then I would recommend to use some kind of pipe through injecting a custom script into the webpage.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `window.setTimeout` and take a snapshot using page.render? So your code would change to:

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
   page.sendEvent('click', 650, 430);
}, 5000);
window.setTimeout(function() {
   page.render('foo.png');
});
```

The time out will give the ajax call a chance to complete. The render will let you see what the page is supposed to look like when the ajax call is done.